# Как итерерироваться по Map в typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript

Использую `Angular 2`. У меня есть сервис `StatisticsService` с таким методом:

```
getComingStatistics(): Promise<Map<String, number>> {
    const url = `${this.eventUrl}/rest/report/statistic/coming`;
    return this.http.get(url)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => {

            return response.json().data as Map<String, number>
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

В одном из компонентов я делаю такой вызов данного метода:

```
constructor(private statisticsService: StatisticsService) {}

comingStatistics: Map<String, number>;
allComingUsers: number;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.statisticsService.getComingStatistics().then(comingStatistics => {
        console.log(comingStatistics);
        console.log(comingStatistics.values());
    });
}
```

Проблема в том, что на строке `console.log(comingStatistics.values());` у меня падает исключение `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: comingStatistics.values is not a function`.

Ни один из методов `map`'а (таких как `keys()`, `forEach` и т.д.) не работает с аналогичным исключением. Единственный способ взять значение:

```
comingStatistics['someKey']
```

Вопрос. Как мне вытащить все ключи со значениями из данного отображения (карты) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
return response.json().data as Map<String, number>
```

Этим вы лишь говорите компилятору typescript как следует воспринимать получаемый ответ, это не значит, что он автоматически преобразуется к этому типу.

На выходе мы получаем обычный object, и соответственно его можно итерировать любыми удобными средствами: for..in, Object.keys(comingStatistics)